# EF Core Update and Delete Multiple rows

Tags: c#

For example, I called some order details.

```
var list = db.OrderDetails.Where(x=> x.OrderId==1);
```

So, I got some results.

```
{OrderId=1, Id=11, Item="AA", Qty=3}
{OrderId=1, Id=12, Item="BB", Qty=1}
{OrderId=1, Id=13, Item="CC", Qty=2}
```

Then, I want to delete one line, and update 2lines, then want to save it to db.

```
{OrderId=1, Id=11, Item="AA", Qty=31}
{OrderId=1, Id=13, Item="CC", Qty=22}
```

```
db.SaveChange();
```

how do I do easily update and delete simultaneously?

remove one line and db.OrderDetails.Update(list) automatically remove line on db?

Comment: Why does it have to be simultaneous? Or do you just mean in the same transaction?

Comment: `SaveChanges` will perform all the inserts / updates / deletes you have prepared. So is this an XY problem where you're really asking about how to bind asp.net changes or something?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `UpdateRange` and `RemoveRange` functions that is part of the DB context.

So something like:

```
db.OrderDetails.UpdateRange(records);
db.OrderDetails.RemoveRange(records);
```